# For loop to process a list of all students and their online status

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I'm trying to write a "for loop"( has to bee done as a for loop ) that uses the variable prefix which contains the class id, that will process all students matching the id and indicating if they are online.

```
for i in $prefix
do
name=$(grep $i /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f5)
echo -u |grep  "$i"  || test && echo "$name is Online"  || echo "$name is 
Offline"
done
```

The output I get is

```
 John Doe
 Jane Smith
 Ravey Smith is currently offfline
```

The output I need to get is

```
John Doe is online
Jane Smith is offline
Ravey Smith is online
```

Comment: `for i in $name; do....`

Comment: You can use this line of code: `who|grep $name > /dev/null && echo "$name is online" || echo "$name is offline"`

Comment: when I execute `echo -u `, I get back `-u`. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `echo -u |grep  "$i" `. Good luck!